# Subquery returned more than 1 value error with Job

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have created a job to be executed once the ssrs subscription failed for any reason.

This job works perfectly if only one subscription failure occured.
the last time I had 3 failure.
the job : show this error :

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I have tried to replace = with IN but did not work so it can except multiple values.

```
DECLARE @ScheduleId NVARCHAR (50)
SET
  @ScheduleId = (
    SELECT
      rs.ScheduleID
    FROM
      ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c WITH(NOLOCK)
      INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions sub WITH(NOLOCK) ON (c.ItemID = (sub.Report_OID))
      INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rs WITH(NOLOCK) ON (
        c.ItemID = (rs.ReportID)
        AND sub.SubscriptionID IN (rs.SubscriptionID)
      )
      INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Schedule sch WITH(NOLOCK) ON (rs.ScheduleID = (sch.ScheduleID))
      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj WITH(NOLOCK) ON (cast(rs.ScheduleID as sysname) = (sj.name)) --sysname equivalent to nvarchar(128)
      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules sjs WITH(NOLOCK) ON (sj.job_id = (sjs.job_id))
      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules ss WITH(NOLOCK) ON (sjs.schedule_id = (ss.schedule_id))
    WHERE
      (
        sub.LastStatus = 'Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 1 errors.'
        OR sub.LastStatus LIKE '%Failure%'
      )
  )
```

Could you please assist in this

Comment: If there is more than one schedule, what do you want to happen? Do you want to return just one, or do you want to amend your query to deal with all of them? As an aside, you may wish to read this: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead.

```
DECLARE @ScheduleId NVARCHAR (50)
SET
  @ScheduleId = (
    SELECT
      TOP 1 rs.ScheduleID
    FROM
      ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c WITH(NOLOCK)
      INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions sub WITH(NOLOCK) ON (c.ItemID = (sub.Report_OID))
      INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rs WITH(NOLOCK) ON (
        c.ItemID = (rs.ReportID)
        AND sub.SubscriptionID IN (rs.SubscriptionID)
      )
      INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Schedule sch WITH(NOLOCK) ON (rs.ScheduleID = (sch.ScheduleID))
      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj WITH(NOLOCK) ON (cast(rs.ScheduleID as sysname) = (sj.name)) --sysname equivalent to nvarchar(128)
      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules sjs WITH(NOLOCK) ON (sj.job_id = (sjs.job_id))
      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules ss WITH(NOLOCK) ON (sjs.schedule_id = (ss.schedule_id))
    WHERE
      (
        sub.LastStatus = 'Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 1 errors.'
        OR sub.LastStatus LIKE '%Failure%'
      )
  )
```